# How to get the current degree of RotateAnimation in Android?

Tags: android, rotateanimation

I have a semi circle that I rotate 180 degrees. If the user presses reset during the RotateAnimation, I want to have a reset animation that goes from currentDegree back to 0. Currently the reset animation goes from 180 to 0, but this looks strange if the animation hasn't finished yet.

I have:

```
final RotateAnimation resetAnim = 
  new RotateAnimation(-180f, 0f, width, height/2);
```

I want something like:

```
final RotateAnimation resetAnim = 
  new RotateAnimation(currentDegreeOfAnimation, 0f, width, height/2);
```

Comment: What about calculating it from the animation duration and the difference between start time of animation and time of reset being pressed? A bit of a hack and possibly not very accurate but I don't see anything in the `RotateAnimation` or `Animation` classes which would do what you want directly.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of the rotation is:

```
(EndDegree - StartDegree)/Duration
```

The total time it has been rotating is:

```
currentTime - startTime
```

And the current degree is:

```
speed*time
```

I believe you have access to all of these variables through getters, except for current time which is just System.currentTimeMillis(), don't forget to keep your units straight.

Comment: if the i pause the rotate animation this will no longer work will it? starttime will be distorted.

Comment: It wouldn't be quite so simple, no. If pausing is a factor then you will need to account for downtime as well and subtract it from the total time.